# How to change snackbar background color in .Net Maui?

Tags: maui

I have a snackbar in .Net Maui 7 created like this :

```
    var options = new SnackbarOptions
    {
        BackgroundColor = Colors.White,
        CornerRadius = new CornerRadius(10),
    };
    
    var snackbar = Snackbar.Make(Message, visualOptions:options, anchor:Target, actionButtonText: ActionButtonText);
```

The snackbar shows successfully but the background is not white. It shows dark grey.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Did you test your code on the Windows platform? I have create a new project the test [the example code in the official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/maui/alerts/snackbar?tabs=android#c). When I run it on the android, I can get the same effect as the result picture in the official document. But when I run it on the windows, the background color will always be gray.

I can't make sure this is the limit for the windows or a bug. But you can refer to the official document about [WinUI Specifics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/maui/alerts/snackbar?tabs=android#winui-specifics) or post an new issue on the github.

**Update1:**

I used the following code and can't reproduce your problem.

```
        var snackbarOptions = new SnackbarOptions
        {
            BackgroundColor = Colors.White,
            TextColor = Colors.Black,
            ActionButtonTextColor = Colors.Black,
            CornerRadius = new CornerRadius(10),
            Font = Font.SystemFontOfSize(14),
            ActionButtonFont = Font.SystemFontOfSize(14),
            CharacterSpacing = 0.5
        };
```

The result image:

[image]

And set the TextColor as White:

[image]

Because the background color are both white, the text is not visible.

And the result image with red backgroundcolor:

[image]

Comment: I'm running the code on Android.

Comment: You can check the updated part in my answer. @ThomasCarlton